# Why do points and lines added to a bar plot in R shift when outputted as pdf (but look fine in png)?

Tags: r, pdf

Using the basic graphics in R (working on Windows 8.1), adding lines and points onto a bar plot is simple:

```
bars=c(1,2) #create dummy barplot data
points=c(0.5, 1)  #create dummy points data
mybar=barplot(bars)
lines(x=mybar, y=points, lwd=2)
points(x=mybar, y=points, pch='-', cex=7)
```

But when I output this into a pdf, the points and lines don't match up any more:

```
pdf('barplot.pdf')
mybar=barplot(bars)
lines(x=mybar, y=points, lwd=2)
points(x=mybar, y=points, pch='-', cex=7)
dev.off()
```

[image: Bar plot with points and lines, outputted as a pdf]

Outputting a png works fine, but I need pdfs, so how do I output a pdf, where the lines and points match (like on the png)?

```
png('barplot.png')
mybar=barplot(bars)
lines(x=mybar, y=points, lwd=2)
points(x=mybar, y=points, pch='-', cex=7)
dev.off()
```

[image: Bar plot with points and lines, outputted as a png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen these problems before, and my usual workaround uses `CairoPDF`. This works for me under Windows 7.

Since problems of this type are specific to devices and operating systems, it would help others when you could add information on the operating system.

```
library(Cairo)
CairoPDF('barplot.pdf')
mybar=barplot(bars)
lines(x=mybar, y=points, lwd=2)
points(x=mybar, y=points, pch='-', cex=7)
dev.off()
```